# Possible to create a array of referencetype?

Tags: java, arrays

For example I have a arraylist of objects and I would like to test what kind of object it is.

eg.

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add("StringType");
list.add(5);
list.add(new randomClass());

ArrayList<Class?> define = new ArrayList<Class?>(); // <-- part i dont know what to do
define.add(String);
define.add(int);
define.add(randomClass);

for(x=0; .. ; ..){
if(list.get(x) instanceof define.get(x))
    //do stuff 
}
//Get results if list matches define?
```

Or do I have to store the reference type as String and do a `list.get(x).getClass().toString().equals(define.get(x));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Class<?>` as the type argument for the second list - and then use `Class.isInstance` to perform the check for "instancehood":

```
List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
classes.add(String.class);
classes.add(int.class);
classes.add(RandomClass.class);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (classes.get(i).isInstance(list.get(i))) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I guess i missed out on the <?> part. Another question is, is it possible to make that declaraiton of the list as a 1 liner? eg for a string list : List<String> a = Arrays.asList("a","b")?

Comment: @user755053 `List<Class<?>> classes = Arrays.asList(String.class, Integer.class);`

Comment: @user755053 With Java 8 something like this should work: `list.stream().map(o -> o.getClass()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Oh my how silly of me, I missed out the .class! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I came across another problem, I've edited it into the main question body.

Comment: @user755053: Please roll back that edit and ask a new question. You shouldn't keep extending a question - one question per post.

Comment: Continuation of the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827226/using-an-arraylistclass-for-casting