# Using an ArrayList<Class?> for casting?

Tags: java, casting

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826640/possible-to-create-a-array-of-referencetype)

I have the following code:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add("StringType");
list.add(5);
list.add(new RandomClass());

List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
classes.add(String.class);
classes.add(int.class);
classes.add(RandomClass.class);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (classes.get(i).isInstance(list.get(i))) {
        ...
    }
}

if (isvalid)
 mymethod(...);


public void mymethod(String string, int num, RandomClass randomClass){ }
```

Now I'm trying to cast the object into the right type with a method using a string argument.

Instead of:

```
mymethod( (String) list.get(0), (int) list.get(1), (RandomClass) list.get(2) );
```

I would like to reuse the definition created above for the cast.

```
mymethod( ( define.get(0) ) list.get(0), .... );
```

I've also tried using the Class.cast(obj) but of course it returns a type '?' which again defeats the purpose of casting it again using (String).

Comment: This **cannot** be type safe as you can change the types at runtime made cause a `ClassCastException`. Therefore you **cannot** have what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is type safety?**

> In computer science, type safety is the extent to which a programming
>   language discourages or prevents type errors.

If code is type safe, then the compiler can verify, at compile time, that all the types are correct:

```
String getName() {
    return "name";
}
```

The compiler knows that "name" must be a `String` so it can verify that this code will never throw a type error.

Once you do something like:

```
int getNumber() {
    (int) number;
}
```

The need to explicitly cast to `int` tells you that this code has an error condition, namely when `number` is not of type `int` or a type that is assignable to `int`.

**How does it affect you?**

Your code:

```
define.get(0).cast(list.get(0))
```

You want the return type of this statement to be of the type of `get(0)`. But the compiler has no way of knowing, at compile time, what `define.get(0)` returns. This is inidcated to you by the return type.

You have a `List<Class<?>>`, i.e. a `List` of a class of "I don't care what type". You then use a member of this `List` to cast a member of your other `List` - the only result can be an "I don't care what type".

You can hack around this with:

```
<T> T get(final int i) {
    return (T) define.get(i).cast(list.get(i));
}
```

This will happily compile:

```
final String thing = get(0);
```

As will:

```
final int thing = get(0);
```

i.e. all that you have done is to endogenise the cast. The error condition still exists.

Comment: This solves the problem by the 'hack' there. Before I call them method, I would have checked if each object was of the correct type (isInstance part in the forloop). and if all the parameters were valid I would then call the method. This I assume this shouldnt produces any error of wrong type by using the hack. Mind explaining how does the (t) cast and return value <T> T works. Or maybe a link to readup on that.

Comment: Are you saying that you have never seen [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) before? Hm...

Comment: Oh okay. I've seen it and read bits of it but haven't really did a read up on exactly how it works. School doesn't really teach such stuff so yeah.

Answer (score 2):

`define.get(0).cast(list.get(0))` would attempt to cast `list.get(0)` to the required type.

Comment: Yes i know but for example get(0) it's return value isn't of 'String' type. Which my method definition is method (String string, int num, RandomClass randomclass)

Comment: @user755053 it is not possible to do what you want. Find another approach. This seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to select the appropriate method, the compiler needs to know **at compile time** what the types of the arguments are. Or at least a general category such as `List<?>` etc.

This is needed to support overloading of methods. There can be many methods with the same name, but with different parameter types.

Since you are asking the VM to call a method when it can't determine which exact method you want to call, because it doesn't know **at compile time** what the types of your parameters are, what you ask cannot be done in Java.

Here is the relevant section from the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9).

What it says is that the system selects **at compile time** which method signature to use, and then, at run time, the particular implementation of that method signature that's correct for the given instance.

Comment: I always thought that overloaded method selection occurs at runtime? Where did you read about it happening at compile time? Could you post a link?

Comment: @GermannArlington it is common knowledge that Java is wired at compile time. You may be confusing _overloaded_ methods with _overridden_ methods, which are selected at run time - the latter is called polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to store object's class separately

```
list.get(0).getClass()
```

will get you the class of the stored object and then you can use what @Eran suggested

and

```
list.get(0).getClass().getName()
```

will get you the String name of your class